# ReactJS: Sum Array returns NaN as initial value - set as 0

Tags: reactjs

I am using

```
var resulttw = inputFields.reduce((total, currentValue) => total = total + (currentValue.Weight * currentValue.Quantity),0);
```

To sum an array. However, by default this array is empty, so it's initial state reads NaN. How do I set the initial state of this resulttw to 0?

Comment: You’ve correctly set the accumulator’s init value to 0. When the array is empty, 0 will be returned. I think the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Can you show code that calls this and reproduces the issue?

Comment: Check your inputFields array. Perhaps it consists of non-numeric elements

Comment: What does `inputFields` array contains?

Answer (score 0):

Coincidently, I got the same error today. I always solve this kind of error with `console.log()`.

I know we always want our codes shorter and cleaner. But make it a little long while debugging.

```
var resulttw = inputFields.reduce((total, currentValue) => {
  console.log("Quantity", currentValue.Quantity);
  console.log("Weight", currentValue.Weight);
  total += currentValue.Weight * currentValue.Quantity;
}, 0);
```

Comment: even though this solution wouldn't solve the problem, try as said here, console log.

Comment: it does not solve the problem directly. It will help to see `NaN` and future 'NaN`s.